# How can I remove the focus from a int field control in editor script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void OnEnable()
    {
        _conversationTrigger = (ConversationTrigger)target;
        _conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");

        conversationsList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, _conversations)
        {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,

            drawHeaderCallback = DrawConversationsHeader,

            drawElementCallback = DrawConversationsElement,

            onAddCallback = (list) =>
            {
                SerializedProperty addedElement;
                // if something is selected add after that element otherwise on the end
                if (_currentlySelectedConversationIndex >= 0)
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(list.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);
                }

                var name = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                var foldout = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
                var dialogues = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

                name.stringValue = "";
                foldout.boolValue = false;
                dialogues.arraySize = 0;

                conversationsCounter = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("ConversationIndex");

                GUI.FocusControl("Load Conversations");
            },

            elementHeightCallback = (index) =>
            {
                return GetConversationHeight(_conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index));
            }
        };
    }
```

I have later in the script a button inside OnInspectorGUI :

```
if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(_conversationTrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            _conversationTrigger.LoadConversations();
        }
```

But it's not working I need to click any other control in the editor to make the changed value in the int field to take effect.

Here I'm using the IntField :

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        // if there are no elements reset _currentlySelectedConversationIndex
        if (conversationsList.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1 < _currentlySelectedConversationIndex) _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Conversations", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        {
            newSize = EditorGUILayout.IntField(_conversations.arraySize);
        }
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            if (newSize > _conversations.arraySize)
            {
                // elements have to be added -> how many?
                var toAdd = newSize - _conversations.arraySize - 1;
                // why -1 ? -> We add the first element and set its values to default
                // now if we simply increase the arraySize for the rest of the elements
                // they will be all a copy of the first -> all defaults ;)

                // first add one element
                _conversations.arraySize++;
                // then get that element
                var newIndex = _conversations.arraySize - 1;
                var newElement = _conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(newIndex);

                // now reset all properties like
                var name = newElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                name.stringValue = "";

                // now for the rest simply increase arraySize
                _conversations.arraySize += toAdd;
            }
            else
            {
                // for removing just make sure the arraySize is not under 0
                _conversations.arraySize = Mathf.Max(newSize, 0);
            }
        }

        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Height(250));

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        conversationsList.DoLayoutList();

        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            _conversationTrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(_conversationTrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            _conversationTrigger.LoadConversations();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
```

When I'm typing a new size value in the IntField it's changing in real time the list and add/remove items.

But if I'm setting the IntField to 0 and then click the "Load Conversations" button it will load the items but the value in the intfield will still be 0 instead changing to the number of loaded items.

Only when I click on another control in the editor or even clicking on other window in the pc it's changing the intfield value to the items loaded number value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`EditorGUI.FocusTextInControl`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.FocusTextInControl.html).

---

usually you would call

```
GUI.SetNextControlName("MyTextField");
```

in order to set a certain name (think of it like a label) to the next displayed field and then later on some event call

```
 EditorGUI.FocusTextInControl("MyTextField");
```

in order to set the focus to that field.

---

In your case just wanting to loose the focus and not focus on any field you can simply use

```
EditorGUI.FocusTextInControl(null);
```